# Collaborative Network Documentation per site

Tags: collaboration, document-management

Does anyone know of any good software or solution, for managing network documentation, like diagrams, ip address for devices, contact info, passwords on a per site basis? I can't seem to find anything, even some type of cloud solution would be good. And also to be able to have a team of people to login and look it at as well.

The solution should be rather open source, or a per user price, rather it be hosted or cloud solution, not desktop, no preference of os, and privacy is of importance.

Comment: Should the tool be "aware" of network things? If yes, how? What features would differentiate it from a simple folder where you would store your documentation files? For instance, should it include a network diagram editor?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated it with your original post (note you can always [edit] that). Cleaning up comments, let me repeat the points still open: Must it allow for commercial use? Can you self-host it? What would be your price limit?

Comment: It sounds like you could make this work with any number of generic applications spanning several categories that are more or less suited for storing documentation.  What are your requirements with regards to diagrams? Do you intend to store source files for diagrams  and if so do you need the application to provide versioning control or editing capabilities? What level of security. Auditing? Fine grained access control? Single-sign-on? 2-FA? Do you need any integration with cmdb, network management, device scanners or other data sources? Do you need collaborative authoring? review process?

Comment: To get some ideas you can have a look at the following three tools that are all built specifically with technical documentation in mind, yet are very different in nature. The first is a data center management system  [Device42 Data Center](http://www.device42.com/features/data-center-management/) the second is an enterprise wiki [Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-use-cases-283641068.html) and the last a collaborative authoring tool for mission critical documents [XaitPorter for Engineering](http://www.xait.com/solutions/engineering/)